# H2 limitations with Sysdate and hence cant use in functional test cases

Tags: oracle, jpa, spring-data-jpa, h2

I am using Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA. In my application application is running over Oracle DB and Functional Test cases against the H2 DB.

I've to check if key is expired or not and its a Date field in DB. So Sysdate< ExpiryDate and with Oracle this works fine, but sysdate is not a function in H2 and I simply cant keep two queries 1 for Oracle and Other for H2.

```
@Query("SELECT new com......Test( "
        + "p.id,p.keyId, p.keyType, p.expiryDate...., sysdate) "
        + "FROM Table A p "
       
        + "WHERE ......")
List<EnableEncryptionKeyProjection> findBySrcClientId(....);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `current_timestamp` for both.